# FFMPEG - Encoding video changes sounds and subtitles tracks names, and make them invisible for SmartTV / Chromecast

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles, chromecast, h.265

First of all, I'm not sure this is the right place for such question.
Please let me know if I'm wrong.

### INTRODUCTION:

I'm regularly recording movies on french channels, via a functionality of my NAS.
The resulting files are ***.ts** (I suppose the program behind is ffmpeg or vlc, but can't be sure).

Those records contain multi-lang and subtitles, and any of my players (tv, chromecast, vlc android or win) can see all the channels with the correct names (like french subtitles, french or VO sound tracks etc..).

Then I'm using ffpmeg to cut the advertising, by extracting the desired parts, and merging them via a concat command.
Here are the commands I'm using:

Extract:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel info -i $SOURCE -ss $TIME_START -t $TIME_DURATION -c copy -map 0 -ignore_unknown -y $CHUNK_DESTINATION
```

Concat files:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel info -f concat -safe 0 -i $FFMPEG_LIST_FILE -c copy -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ignore_unknown -y $DESTINATION
```

Up to now, I've been using the static build **ffmpeg-3.0.1-win64-static** for windows, and everything worked like a charm.

### PROBLEM:

Recently, mainly for saving space on my NAS, I decided to switch the video codec to **libx265**. So I had to update the ffmpeg build to the last version available: **ffmpeg-4.1.3-win64-static**.

Then my concat command changes to:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel info -f concat -safe 0 -i $FFMPEG_LIST_FILE -c copy -map 0 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -ignore_unknown -y $DESTINATION
```

My problem is that as soon as I use the newer versions of ffmpeg (above 4.*, I tried several intermediate), the conversion process change the name of the channels (sound and subtitles), and most of my players (Smart TV, chromecast) doesn't see the subtitles anymore.

It happens independently of the video codec. I tried **libx264** and **libx265**, and also different container: I tried with **mkv**, **mp4** and **ts**).

I tried with the explicit "subtitle copy" option of ffmpeg, to be sure it's not trying to convert/re-encode, but without any effect.

I also tried to first cut/concat the movie with the old **ffmpeg-3.0.1-win64-static** with libx264, and then convert to h265 with the new version **ffmpeg-4.1.3-win64-static** and the command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel info -i "The Revenant (2015).ts" -c copy -map 0 -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -ignore_unknown -y "The Revenant (2015) h265.ts"
```

Here are the ffprobe infos for each version, and they are pretty similar..:

```
The Revenant (2015).ts (ffmpeg-3.0.1-win64-static / h264):
----------------------------------------------------------
ffprobe version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mpegts @ 000002b515a5c700] start time for stream 5 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
Input #0, mpegts, from 'C:/zzzz_films_converted/Copi├®/The Revenant (2015).ts':
  Duration: 02:21:59.18, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 3830 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](fre): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 134 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x102](qad): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 149 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x103](qaa): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x104](fra): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006) (hearing impaired)
    Stream #0:5[0x105](fra): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)


The Revenant (2015) h265.ts (ffmpeg-4.1.3-win64-static / h264):
---------------------------------------------------------------
ffprobe version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mpegts @ 0000027d31b3c700] start time for stream 5 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
Input #0, mpegts, from 'C:/zzzz_films_converted/Copi├®/The Revenant (2015) h265.ts':
  Duration: 02:21:59.22, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 1719 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: hevc (Main) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](fre): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 136 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x102](qad): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 137 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x103](qaa): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x104](fra): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006) (hearing impaired)
    Stream #0:5[0x105](fra): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
```

I've googled a lot, but cannot find any similar problem.

I can provide the video files presented here for **testing purpose only**...

Thanks for having read this endless post :)

Comment: Share the readouts for the result of the concat command - working & non-working.

Comment: @Gyan: I didn't kept the logs. I'll redo a concat and post that as soon as I can